# Encapsulate WebSocket Message in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, websocket, encapsulation

I am trying to encapsulate websocket messages into well defined Type.
I have main IIncommingMessage which is the base interface for all incoming messages as such:

```
export interface IIncommingMessage {
  className : IClassName;
  methodName : IMethodName;
}
```

There are various types of class this websocket can call as follows:

```
export type IClassName = IClassA | IClassB | IClassC
```

as well as various method in associated classes

```
export type IMethodName = IfooinClassA | IbarinClassA | IbazinClassB | IquxinClassB | IquuxinClassB | IcorgeinClassC
```

Such that it looks like this

```
ClassA:
  foo()
  bar()

ClassB:
  baz()
  qux()
  quux()

ClassC:
  corge
```

The idea is that if a websocket message arrives. It'll come as

```
{
  className : "ClassB"
  methodName : "qux"
}
```

So this should call ClassB of function qux().

1. The approach I'm taking looks bad. Was wondering if there is a better way to tightly couple the web-socket message to a well defined type
2. Also curious on how i'll make this call in TypeScript - would it be protoype.call('className.method')?

Comment: Are these methods static?

Comment: And do these have to be classes?

Comment: Can it not work without being forced into Static?

Comment: Yes they are different classes that will handle particular messages from the websocket connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your first part to have well defined type this is how I would implement it.

```
class ClassA {
    foo() { }
    bar() { }
}

class ClassB {
    baz() { }
    qux() { }
    quux() { }
}

class ClassC {
    corge() { }
    notAMethod = 1;
}

// This will be a like a dictionary mapping name to class
// Will also be used in the second part.
const Classes = {
    ClassA,
    ClassB,
    ClassC,
};

// This will be 'ClassA'|'ClassB'|'ClassC'
type IClassName = keyof typeof Classes;
type IClassOf<T extends IClassName> = InstanceType<typeof Classes[T]>;
type MethodFilter<T extends IClassName> = { [MN in keyof IClassOf<T>]: IClassOf<T>[MN] extends () => void ? MN : never }
type MethodName<T extends IClassName> = MethodFilter<T>[keyof MethodFilter<T>];

interface IGenericIncomingMessage<T extends IClassName> {
    className: T;
    methodName: MethodName<T>;
}

type IIncomingMessage = IGenericIncomingMessage<'ClassA'> | IGenericIncomingMessage<'ClassB'> | IGenericIncomingMessage<'ClassC'>;

let msg0: IIncomingMessage = {
    className: 'ClassA',
    methodName: 'foo', // valid
}

let msg1: IIncomingMessage = {
    className: 'ClassC',
    methodName: 'corge', // valid
}

let msg2: IIncomingMessage = { // compiler error. Type ... is not assignable to type 'IIncomingMessage'.
    className: 'ClassA',
    methodName: 'corge', 
}

let msg3: IIncomingMessage = {
    className: 'ClassD', // compiler error. ClassD Name is not not in 'ClassA' | 'ClassB' | 'ClassC'
    methodName: 'corge',
}

let msg4: IIncomingMessage = {
    className: 'ClassC',
    methodName: 'notAMethod', // compiler error. Type '"notAMethod"' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "qux" | "quux" | "corge"'.
}
```

So about the second part I use the Classes dictionary I defined earlier to lookup class by name, create a new instance of the class. This means that a malicious message having a valid class name that is not in the dictionary will not work.

```
// I omit error handling here.
function invokeFunction<T extends IClassName>(message: IGenericIncomingMessage<T>): void {
    // Look for the class instance in dictionary and create an instance
    const instance = new Classes[message.className]() as IClassOf<T>;
    // Find the method by name. The cast to any is to silence a compiler error;
    // You may need to perform additional login to validate that the method is allowed.
    const fn = instance[message.methodName] as unknown as () => void;
    fn.apply(instance);
}
```

Comment: This is superb!!! Just one quick question regrading this. What if the className was something like `Class.A` is there a way to map ClassA to message `{  className : "ClassA";  methodName : "foo"}` other than having a mapping file?

Comment: In that case you would have to manually specify the names in the Classes object:
`const Classes = { 'ClassA': Class.A, 'ClassB': Class.B, 'ClassC': Class.C, };`

Comment: Francis's suggestion is would work in that case. He also made some nice edits to improve my answer. Thanks francis.

Comment: Great thanks a lot both SherifElmetainy and @francis duvivier !!! much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for the ignorant question is it possible to append / remove from `let Classes = { 'ClassA': Class.A, 'ClassB': Class.B, 'ClassC': Class.C, };` I thought it'll work just like a set where i could go Classes.push or Classes.add but doesn't seem to work since it's an object. Not sure if there is a way to dynamically add to this Classes variable

Comment: any clue @SherifElmetainy / @francis duvivier? i tried this so far no luck
`let Classes = { };
public registerClass(name : string, className : Function) {
     Object.assign({ name : className }, Classes);
} `

Comment: No, there is no way of dynamically adding to the classes and still have have support from the statical typing system. (That's what the static word is about, it's type checks that you can do without actually executing the code) Unless you can specify in the type which classes can be added.

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks a lot Francis!!! It makes sense now.